# Install4j, "File Associations" (selection) screen does not appear in Unix installer

Tags: install4j

When creating installers with multiple file associations, the "File Associations" screen in the installer (which allows the user to select/deselect which extensions to associate with the application being installed) appears in the Windows installer created, but does not appear in the Unix shell installer.  This means all file associations are made without the user getting to choose.

Is there a way to force the appearance of the file associations screen?

Answer (score 2):

This is indeed a bug in install4j, it will be fixed in 8.0.3, please contact support@ej-technologies.com to get a build where this is already fixed.